# What is the meaning of "完败"?

Tags: simplified-characters

客队0比3完败。

客队0比3完败主队。

客队3比0完败主队。

客队以完败收场。

客队0比3完胜了。

客队3比0完败了。

What is the meaning of "完败" in these sentence?

Comment: https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%AE%8C%E8%B4%A5

Comment: no object -> to be completely defeated, 
has object -> to win a clear victory

Answer (score 1):

Entirely/completely defeated, without any score.  See, all your examples are nothing to 3, hence, the other (winning) side is 完胜：主队3:0完胜客队。

Answer (score 0):

I remember an example for "败":

江苏队打败了北京队赢得了冠军。

It's a fuzzy sentence. We should add something:

1. 江苏队打败了北京队，赢得了冠军。(Jiangsu wins the champion and Beijing loses)
2. 江苏队打败了，北京队赢得了冠军。(Jiangse loses and Beijing wins the champion)

In the second example, 江苏队打败了 means "Jiangsu loses" but not "Jiangsu wins" because it is "Jiangsu fights with Beijing and loses". It's the same as "客队3比0完败主队。". We don't use "客队3比0完败了。". We use "客队3比0赢了。". In other examples, they are the same as the first example, meaning "lose".